# How to print info from a class within a class?

Tags: c++

I am creating a enqueue program, have to enqueue customer to a queue.
However, after enqueued into the queue, I cannot print out the correct info. 
I created 2 class Customer and CustomerQueue.

this is the functions for customer class:

```
Customer::Customer (char *name, int age)
{
    this -> name = name;
    this -> age = age;
    this -> sex = 'S';
}

void Customer::printCustomer () const
{
    if (age >= 65)
    {
        cout << "Senior " << name
             << " (age " << age << ")";
    }
    else if (sex == 'F')
        cout << "Miss " << name;
    else
        cout << "Mr " << name;
}
```

In the private section in CustomerQueue class:

```
private:
        struct Node;
        typedef Node* NodePtr;

        struct Node
        {
            CustomerType ct;
            Customer cust;
            NodePtr next;
        };
```

Functions for CustomerQueue class and enum for Customer Type:

```
enum CustomerType {Senior, Lady, Other};

void CustomerQueue::enqueue (Customer newCust, CustomerType type)
{
    NodePtr prev, curr;
    findPosition (prev, curr, type);

    if (prev == NULL || curr == NULL)
        addToTail (newCust, type);
    else
    {
        NodePtr temp = new Node;
        temp -> ct = type;
        temp -> cust = newCust;

        if (compare (type, curr -> ct) == 0)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr -> next;
        }
        prev -> next = temp;
        temp -> next = curr;
        ++no;
    }
}

void CustomerQueue::printGeneral () const
{
    NodePtr temp = head;

    cout << "Whole queue information" << endl;
    int i = 1;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << i << ": " << temp -> ct;
        getCust (temp -> cust);
        temp = temp -> next;
        i++;
    }
}

void CustomerQueue::getCust (Customer aCust) const
{
    aCust.printCustomer ();
}
```

in the main function, i do this to print out the queue.

```
aQueue.printGeneral ();
```

Output

> Whole queue information
>   1: 1Senior @ (age 4508754)-

Which part is wrong, why the output of name and age are weird symbols.

Comment: Verifiable example please. What's your main function?

Comment: @user202729, i have a function within the main function

Answer (score 0):

From the constructor `Customer::Customer(char *name, int age)`, I would guess the `name` member is a `char*` as well.

In `CustomerQueue::enqueue (Customer newCust, CustomerType type)`, you pass a `Customer` by value. This means it must be copied onto the stack, and copying needs a copy constructor, especially when you have pointers in the `Customer` class.

Same goes for assignment as in `temp -> cust = newCust;`.

In this case, you can avoid this by using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), e.g.

```
class Customer {
public:
    // ...
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    char sex;
};
```

---

If you cannot or don't want to use `std::string`, you must allocate and free the memory yourself. This also means defining a copy constructor, a copy assignment operator, and a destructor.

See also the rule of three at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)

Comment: I have a copy constructor. so temp -> cust = newCust will not work? it will not assign to the cust in the class?

Comment: how ever i tried  temp -> cust (newCust); it gave error.

Comment: @engkhsky It should be `temp->cust = newCust;`, and you need to define an assignment operator. The copy constructor is only used when initializing a new variable, not when assigning to an existing variable.